# Possible Overlapping Schengen Visas

Tags: business-travel, schengen-visas, vacations

I am from the Philippines. I have a Schengen visa application scheduled on June 01 via the German Embassy. The nature of the Schengen visa application will be for the purpose of business with a (target) travel date of June 26 to June 29/30.

I have an ongoing Schengen visa application via the Netherlands Embassy for a vacation trip on July 12 to 24 for these countries

- Netherlands, Amsterdam
- Croatia, Split
- Italy, Rome

Assuming that my Schengen visa application for the Netherlands is approved, would there be any concern regarding my Schengen visa application for Germany?

Comment: Why do you think there would be an issues with your application for Germany ? And how can you apply when you have an ongoing application, haven't you deposited your passport at the Dutch embassy ?

Comment: If would be up to the German consulate to issue a visa (if they do) that doesn't overlap the Dutch one. They can be issued with back-to-back validity if necessary.